# t-sql i am transforming data

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am transforming data from this legacy table: 
 **MovTime (IdMov INT, IdPerson NVARCHAR(20), Date1 datetime, Type1 nvarchar(30) )**

```
IdMov       IdPerson             Date1                   Type
----------- -------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------
1           David                2012-06-01 09:00:00.000 Entered
2           David                2012-06-01 12:30:00.000 Exit
3           David                2012-06-01 14:00:00.000 Entered
4           David                2012-06-01 18:30:00.000 Exit
5           Kim                  2012-06-02 09:00:00.000 Entered
6           Kim                  2012-06-02 12:00:00.000 Exit
```

... I want the result to be the following:

```
IdPerson     Data        Total Time
----------  ----------  ----------
David       2012-06-01   08:00:00 
Kim         2012-06-02   03:00:00
```

T-SQL

```
declare @WK_TABLE TABLE (IdMov INT, IdPerson NVARCHAR(20), Date1 datetime, Type1 nvarchar(30)) 

Insert into @WK_TABLE values(1,'David', '2012-06-01 09:00', 'Entered')
Insert into @WK_TABLE values(2,'David', '2012-06-01 12:30', 'Exit')
Insert into @WK_TABLE values(3,'David', '2012-06-01 14:00', 'Entered')
Insert into @WK_TABLE values(4,'David', '2012-06-01 18:30', 'Exit')
Insert into @WK_TABLE values(5,'Kim', '2012-06-02 09:00', 'Entered')
Insert into @WK_TABLE values(6,'Kim', '2012-06-02 12:00', 'Exit')


select * from @WK_TABLE
```

Can someone  help me?

Comment: What happes if you have a row with entered and no corresponding exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no shift can ever be more than 24 hours (e.g. extend into the next day), and that there is some constraint preventing rows without a corresponding enter/exit:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT IdPerson, Date1, Type1, rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (PARTITION BY IdPerson ORDER BY Date1)
  FROM @WK_TABLE
)
SELECT 
  x.IdPerson, [Data] = CONVERT(DATE, x.Date1), 
  [Total Time] = CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(MINUTE, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.Date1, x2.Date1)), '00:00:00')) 
FROM x INNER JOIN x AS x2
ON x.IdPerson = x2.IdPerson 
AND x.rn = x2.rn - 1
AND x.TYpe1 = 'Entered' AND x2.type1 = 'Exit'
GROUP BY x.IdPerson, CONVERT(DATE, x.Date1)
ORDER BY [Data], IdPerson;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron ;). Works 100%

Comment: @Pankaj what is the rush? Maybe a better answer will come along.